# Add individual Android classes as dependencies?

Tags: android, maven

I'm developing a server application which is communicating with Android clients and it needs some classes of the Android framework (e.g. `android.location.Location`). Is it possible to add specific Android classes to a project with maven? 
I ended up adding the complete framework but this is not very elegant.

Comment: The only real option would be to extract the classes you care about and create a new artifact. IMO this is more brittle.

Comment: Don't you think using android classes (some of which for sure depends on native code, and some have no sence outside of Android) is not recommended? What the particular purpose of this?

Comment: I agree with you that this is not something which is recommended for a productive system. But the the application is a prototype for purely academic purposes and has a limited lifetime. Directly using Android classes is being done to save the time needed to design proper interfaces:)

Comment: Then save even more time and just use the Android framework. If your goal is elegance as stated, take the time to extract the interfaces-depending on what you actually need you may be able to automate part of that process anyway.

Comment: I guess you are right.